# Unity On Top of Full Screen Apps With Multiple Monitors

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, multiple-monitors

I use an nvidia graphics card with multiple monitors on ubuntu 14.04. However its extremely frustrating to use because if I have anything open in fullscreen on one monitor, unity will always appear on top of that application.

This problem only occurs if I am using 3 displays with one of the displays using the clone option. My typical setup is two monitors and a tv connected via hdmi cloning the output of one the two monitors.

If I add the TV as a seperate display rather than cloning an existing one the problem disappears.

I tried Legacy fullscreen support on compiz settings but the problem still persists...